# php7 session_start() times out page

Tags: php

I recently got back into programming in PHP and I've encountered a strange issue. Using `session_start()` on any .php file causes the server to time out and return `This webpage is not available`. I have Session Support and cookies both enabled.

Literally only this will time out my server:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

I've used this code in the past to manage logins but I've only now had this problem. Has something changed? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP7, The options parameter was added for [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

See more about [session configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

In addition to the normal set of configuration directives, a `read_and_close` option may also be provided. If set to **TRUE**, this will result in the session being closed immediately after being read.

Perhaps the issue is related to the [use_only_cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) variable that you can find in the Session's section of the `php.ini` file. Apache will crash if the `use_only_cookies` variable in the Session's section is set to 0 and everything is fine if it's set to 1.

You also checked that the [use_strict_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) should be set to 1.