# Sessions not working after upgrade to PHP 7

Tags: php, session

**My host provider upgraded from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 and I've noticed that session variables are lost after page reload.**
I've rewritten the question based on the ongoing testing to provide relevant information.

Basically, I store search keys, number of rows per page and other data in session variables and they are defined when you are redirection to pagination. However, when I click on any pagination links  - session variables lose their values, in simple words - once on pagination.php sessions stop working.
It is possible to go to the pagination.php either by clicking on a category link (href) or by entering a search term and submitting a form.

Here are the relevant parts of the code, e.g. search form on home page :

```
session_start();
//ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp');
//phpinfo();
//echo "path" . session_save_path();
//if (!session_start()) echo "Session not started";
echo "header session status= " . session_status();
echo "header session_id= " . session_id();

unset($_SESSION['zip']);
unset($_SESSION['keywords']);
unset($_SESSION['key1']);
unset($_SESSION['key2']);


?>
    <div id="searchBox"> 
            <form action="<?php echo $forsaleurl;?>customer/pagination.php" method="post" class="searchform">

                    <input name="searchstring" class="textbox" type="text" placeholder="search string" value="" required/>
                    <input name="postcode" class="textbox" type="text" placeholder="postcode (optional)" value=""/>
                    <input name="submit" class="submit" value="Search" type="submit" />

    </form>

            </div>
```

When site is loaded, the session_status=2 and session_id has a value.

This is the start of pagination.php that creates and displays page links:

```
<?php

include '../config.php';
if ($DEBUG > 0)
           {
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
}

echo "page session status= " . session_status();
echo "page session_id" . session_id();
```

This will echo session_status=1 and blank session_id however you get here.

This is the first part of config.php that starts the session:

```
<?php

ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ERROR); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp');
//phpinfo();
echo "path" . session_save_path();

if (!session_id()) session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

//session_start();
echo session_status();
echo "session_id" . session_id();
```

This will show session_status, session_id and session variables on site load but not after you get to the pagination.

I tried using relative URL in form action but it did not make a difference.

Session files contain either redirects to / or to index.php or to the links I HAVE NOT visited (???).

Site URL is https://themarket.onl.

**Has anyone experienced this issue after upgrade?** The site has been fully working prior to that and no changes were made to the code.

Here is a partial dump of phpinfo() , not sure if session.save_path should not be blank, but it seems to work and local php.ini fails to change the value.

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly no value    no value
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  4   4
session.sid_length  32  32
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1   1
session.use_only_cookies    1   1
session.use_strict_mode 0   0
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

/tmp has drwxr-xr-x permissions.

Comment: I might be missing something here but $category is not set when you do $_SESSION['category'] =$category ;

Comment: @Kevdev $category gets value from the URL and other variables also have a value when first landing on this page. e.g if coming from Catgories it will echo category=Vacanciescat=Vacancies. They are stored in session variables.

Comment: Enable error reporting. That may have been set differently in your previous installation of PHP.

Comment: Enabled but it made no difference to the output.

Comment: To add: echo session_id() returns null, so something has changed around session_start() as it seems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960254/1839439

Comment: "7.1.0 session_start() now returns FALSE and no longer initializes $_SESSION when it failed to start the session." - [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: SOLVED: pagination.php had these lines at the top: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                         Can anyone tell why this became a problem after upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser, this includes any HTML. Even using error reporting as you are here; or ANYTHING that gets displayed in the browser; yes even `echo 'Hi'`; or a blank space; or a BOM before the `<?php`, requires that headers be sent (to display that message or blank).  Headers can only be sent to the browser ONCE, so `session_start()` can't do its thing. (This answer courtesy of my blank-white-screen-of-death error reporting hell for the past day.)